# Why can't i access my apache server outside my LAN

Tags: apache, lamp

I'm using lamp in my linux Operating system.I have configured my router to forward port 80 to my laptop where the apache server is setup. And my apache server is also listening in port 80.
But when i access my public IP outside my LAN I get *"This site can’t be reached"*

What am I missing over here?

Comment: Could you try to access your laptop private IP from inside your network? Do you reach you site?

Comment: What IP is apache set to listen on?

Comment: yes, i can access  my laptop from private ip.

Comment: sorry @Lix i don't get your question. does apache listens to ports and router is used to forward the port 80 to my laptop? please explain if i'm wrong

Comment: @UniqueKiddo - I'm talking about this directive in the apache config - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen

Comment: my httpd.conf file in /opt/lamp/apache2/httpd.conf has this:

`Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>`